# In “Crux Magi” what didn't the squad want?

Tags: star-magi

> "So what's the plan boss?" Kase asked."
>
> Jennix turned to her squad and looked at them in turn "I wouldn’t hold it against you if you didn't want to..."

Page 50

If you didn’t want to.. what?
I didn’t understand the paragraph above could you explain it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed immediately afterwards. They're faced with overwhelming odds and their own small force is unlikely to turn the tide. The obvious thing to do would be to surrender to the enemy, or flee back to their own lines in order to regroup.

The implication is that she wouldn't hold it against them if they didn't want ***[to embark on a foolhardy set of actions that's likely to lead to their annihilation for very little military gain]***.

> Jennix could only nod as she took in the scene before her. **There were
> more Accord ships than there were Templar ships, and yet Jennix knew
> that this was close to the entire fleet of the Order. There was
> nothing more to throw at the Accord, there was nothing left.**
>
> Nothing of significance, anyway.
>
> So this really might be the end, she thought. This could be it. She
> wondered where their leaders were. What were they doing? Were they
> fighting with everyone else?
>
> “So, what’s the plan, boss?” Kase asked.
>
> Jennix turned to her squad and looked at them in turn. “I wouldn’t
> hold it against you if you didn’t want to…”
>
> “Fray that,” Alren cut in.
>
> “I hoped you’d say that.”
>
> “Was there any doubt?” Megn asked.
>
> “No, there wasn’t. **Alright then, we fight. Let’s see how many we can
> take down. Deus, you have the ship. Knights, let’s see what we can
> do.”**

Comment: What does “fray me” means? And what “looked them in turn” means?

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley - Fray is an analogue for "fuck". Looking at then in turn just means looking at them one at a time.